# Angular2 how to bind to a custom component input parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I've a custom component for displaying phone numbers (stm-phone-number).  It has an `@Input()` parameter called `phoneNumber`.  When I try to bind data to it in a `*ngFor`, I get this error message:

> Can't bind to 'phoneNumber' since it isn't a known property of 'stm-phone-number'.

Here's my code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

import { KeyValueModel } from '../../models/types/key-value';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'stm-phone-number',
    templateUrl: './phone-number.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './phone-number.css' ],
    providers: [],
    directives: []
})
export class PhoneNumberComponent implements OnInit 
{
    @Input() phoneNumber: KeyValueModel<string,string>; 

    constructor ()
    {
    }


    ngOnInit()
    {
    }
}
```

and here's how I'm using it:

```html
<section class="grid-block" *ngFor="let entry of PhoneNumberList">
    <stm-phone-number [phoneNumber]="entry"></stm-phone-number>
</section>
```

NOTE: `PhoneNumberList` is an array of `KeyValueModel<string,string>`

How do you bind an iterative value inside `ngFor` to an `@Input` property of a custom component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `PhoneNumberComponent` to the `directives: [...]` list of the module where you are using it or import the module that contains `PhoneNumberComponent` (>= RC.5) otherwise the component will not be instantiated, which is usually what leads to the error you mentioned.